# Windows version of Mac App

Tags: objective-c, windows, macos, cocoa

I have a Mac App that uses the NSKeyedArchiver to save persistent data and it all works fine, but thinking ahead ideally I would like to be able to create a windows version. The current App is all in objective-c using cocoa as I did not think of portability when I first started writing it. I would be happy to make a windows version from scratch but obviously the two need to share data. I am a complete beginner when it come to cross-platform apps. What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to find (or write) code/a library to read NSKeyedArchiver plists on Windows, or you need to release an update to your Mac app that converts the keyed archives to something more generic, like a JSON- or XML-based format.

Comment: And if you want your file to non-readable for users encrypt it with AES (all platforms could decrypt if they have the key)